# array of strings into array of objects with one attribute each?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

How can I turn the below array

```
['12345', '83747']
```

into the below array of objects

```
[ {'id': '12345'}, {'id': '83747'} ]
```

using map?

My attempt so far, `iDs` is an empty array, chunk is an array of string.:

```
obj.iDs.concat(
            chunk.map((item) => ({
                id: item,
            })),
        );
```

An example, my IDE reports no issues with this code:

```
const body = [{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'},{'id':'1234'}]

const batchGetRequestObj = {
        ids: [],
        targetProperties: ['contentID, updateDateTime'],
    };

function func() {
        try {
        chunkArray(
            body.map((item) => {
                return item.id;
            }),
            25,
        ).forEach((chunk) => {
            batchGetRequestObj.ids.concat(
                chunk.map((item) => ({
                    ids: item,
                })),
            );
            console.log(batchGetRequestObj);
        });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

function chunkArray(array: string[], size: number) {
    const slicedArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += size) {
        slicedArray.push(array.slice(i, i + size));
    }
    return slicedArray;
}
```

[Link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxg9gdgzgLgAgEYQCYE8EF4EG0DeA5AJaqEBchAjAEwDMALIQL4A0RpF19TbHZlWoxbsSA7sL5iuQ3qM6CeI-jKVSFEuSsWT542cuk6tRzYY0H1+tXtW7tZq3ZMWbDy7ePnr90x-dufoGuviEuPuHO3lFOXswAuqCgkLCISACGcGAAFgDiAKZwAEr5AI4ArvnwAPJIAFbYCPigCK1traQw5HjxrC3tbXDpAE4A5oUACsMQAA75w3DEVd24hClw+VBwAJIAIqwI5TOomfm7pwAqxAC2+YS9-a3MANxJIABm5VBgi9AIn98ABQASiajwGcGGmGaIAGbRyXwA1gBBYbDdLoQHguGtFAYAB013SM0BgOIG2uoKwAD4wbCcQzhoVysMoAhyflrvjSK96QynsC+nz+TQAKxChnA-HvCDDACi6RypIRUERVNpMP5bQyWTyhRKFSqcFqdW5qBg+JSYEyWOFWtaKsRhOJpI5lOwtMBmvtDM63TdEp9bWYwMF2JxwN5PpSMAgABt8vi4xBRoCdTkCsUypUavVI+GBVHgwhrbqEID8qDvXCY-HE8nU5Wi09QMw3gCfsQ-o7UejMSM+914MNiFBRrheggYMQAF75bpQcrXJDzKvgmOIGBx4hgfKoXsYxoT5v-WXlhOIYiNAAMz3ZCAAPAgBxik5tRnBsnerwBqHDTuc1ztNotx3PcD3QfEZnKGBskBF9INA3cyQOX8p1nSt82FNthSZOAWTZJDwLRDFeWYIA)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: updated with what i have so far

Comment: Your map is correct? What are you struggling with?

Comment: it outputs an empty array

Comment: What is `chunk` then?

Comment: my array of strings

Comment: Please make sure the example is an accurate [mcve]. At the moment the issue you're facing cannot be replicated with the current example

Comment: the problem seems to be the concat.  it isnt adding to the empty array

Comment: I don't see why. As long as `obj.iDs` is an array, it should work.

Comment: ill work on an example

Comment: added example..

Comment: what are you doing here? `func()` can be summed up as `batchGetRequestObj.ids.push(...body.map(item => ({ ids: item.id })))` the rest is just converting stuff things and then later doing the reverse.

Comment: im chunking into 25 items, what i really need is an array of arrays, each sub array contains 25 objects in format `{ 'id': '1234' }`

Comment: spose i could just chunk the final array..

Comment: You take a long array with objects, map out the ids, group those into chunks of 25 ids, then convert for each chunk the id back into an object with an id, and concat these chunks of new objects back into a single long array `batchGetRequestObj.ids`. The only difference between before and after I could see is that you renamed the property from `id` to `ids`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using concat, which doesn't mutate the arrays - you'll have to set the values back to the variable

```
   var arr = ['12345', '83747']
   var newids = obj.ids.concat(arr.map( str => { return {"id" : str}});
   obj.ids = newids
```

Comment: Thx. OP didn't have that code at the time. But I updated my answer for `concat`

Comment: They hadn't. (this is why I wait until someone shows an example of their effort before answering)

Comment: example added above

Comment: @notAChance - the same `concat` issue will happen with your updated code. See my answer above. In your new code `batchGetRequestObj.ids = batchGetRequestObj.ids.concat(...`

Comment: @JohnTyner thanks, I without fail ALWAYS forget this.

Comment: I would however like the final array to contain sub arrays of 25 items each... perhaps another question.